# Font Awesome extras.less variables

Tags: css, less, font-awesome

In the Font Awesome version 2.3.2 less folder I find the file extras.less.

What does the below mean?

```
    @-moz-keyframes spin {
  0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -moz-transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes spin {
  0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -o-transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
  0% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -ms-transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font Awesome uses CSS3 to spin FA icons - [see the examples](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/). Just add `fa-spin` to the class on your FA's `i` tag.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I see that in that file the class fa-spin, or icon-spin in the old version, is defined so you can make the icon spin. However, what I don't understand is what the rules off CSS is doing exactly, these rules are on there own and as far as I can see not related to fa-spin or icon-spin.

Comment: The animation name `spin` is applied to `fa-spin`, then the `@keyframes` declaration adds properties to the animation. [Here's a good explanation](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/).